# Update layer security groups

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-opsworks

I have an OpWorks stack setup with layers and instances.
On one of the layers I decided I needed a new security attached to it. I attached the group but it is not being applied to the EC2 instance.

Is there a command anywhere to perform the applying of the security group changes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've probably figured this out by now, but if anyone else stumbles over the same problem - you need to rebuild the EC2 instances in order for them to pick up the new security group assignment.

Changes within already assigned security groups are applied immediately, but security groups themselves get assigned to instances upon launch only.

Comment: do you know if they supplied a recipe to run to update them?

Comment: They dont supply a recipe, but reading through documentation:

Comment: "After you add a security group to a layer, AWS OpsWorks adds it to all new and restarted instances. AWS OpsWorks does not add security groups to online instances."    
    
So you should be able to pick up new security group by restarting.    
     
Also, there's another option - if you access the EC2 via EC2 console rather than Opsworks, you can change security groups (go to EC2, select your Opsworks instance, Actions ->Networking -> Change Security Groups).